# Can I provide custom TTL for message if queue has TTL for messages already?

Tags: rabbitmq

If my queue `queue1` has property: `x-message-ttl`: 60000, but for part of the messages in this queue I want TTL 120000 or no TTL at all.

TLDR: All messages by default in this queue lives 1 minute, but part of them 2 minutes or has no time to live at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ has separate mechanisms for setting per-queue and per-message TTLs, as described [in the online manual](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html). Using both at once is explicitly mentioned on that page:

> When both a per-queue and a per-message TTL are specified, the lower value between the two will be chosen.

As such, neither of your examples will work:

- Queue-level TTL of 1 minute + message-level TTL of 2 minutes => message will be deleted after 1 minute
- Queue-level TTL of 1 minute + no message-level TTL => message will be deleted after 1 minute

But other combinations would work:

- Queue-level TTL of 1 minute + message-level TTL of 30 seconds => message will be deleted after 30 seconds
- Queue-level TTL of 2 minutes + message-level TTL of 1 minute => message will be deleted after 1 minute

This kind of makes sense: a message can end up in multiple queues, so if it specifies a TTL of 30 seconds, it shouldn't last longer than that in any of them; and a queue that's told to delete messages after 30 seconds doesn't care about individual message settings.